# Qu'est-ce que « moi y en a comprendre » veut dire ?

Tags: pronoms

L'expression « moi y en a + infinitif » ou « toi y en a + infinitif » apparaissent de nombreuses fois dans le livre Obélix et Co. (une des livres Asterix). C'est une construction grammaticale un peu étrange, parce que le pronom du sujet est *moi* plutôt que *je*. Je pense d'après le contexte que c'est une construction très formelle et pas courante, mais j'aimerais la comprendre si c'est possible. J'ai cherché dans des dictionnaires mais je n'ai pas pu trouver cette construction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C’est du [petit nègre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petit_n%C3%A8gre). Cette formule est utilisée pour signifier que le locuteur ne maîtrise pas le français, en général parce que ce n’est pas sa langue maternelle mais plutôt la langue du colonisateur.

Elle n’est en aucun cas formelle.

De nos jours une telle formule peut choquer. À éviter donc dans la plupart des emplois.

Answer (score 7):

C'est une construction incorrecte qui est censée se moquer d'une personne non francophone (et évoque quelqu'un originaire d'Afrique subsaharienne, au moins pour les plus âgés des francophones) parlant mal le français.

On peut faire une explication « à tiroirs » de cette façon de parler.

**Moi** est normalement pronom complément mais on le trouve parfois à la place du sujet, avec ou sans « je ».
Il est possible, de dire en français « moi, je », c'est familier et parfois jugé comme incorrect. Ça permet d'insister sur le « je ».

> Moi je suis bien d'accord avec lui.

On le trouve aussi tout seul en sujet d'une proposition participe :

> Moi partie, tu te retrouveras seul.

ou infinitive :

> Moi, mentir ? Jamais !

Bien sûr, ceci n'est pas réservé à *je* mais vaut aussi bien pour *toi*, *lui*, etc.

Le **glissement** du pronom personnel sujet première personne (qui devrait ici « je ») à un pronom personnel sujet, en quelque sorte « impersonnel », **il**.

**Y**  représentant une prononciation défectueuse de « il » et/ ou de « il y ». Fréquent chez les très jeunes enfants, certains adultes parlant mal ou vite le disent aussi.

> Y'en a que pour lui !
>
> Pierre y m'a tapé.

Jusqu'à il y a une quarantaine d'année le slogan de la poudre chocolatée Banania était « *y'a bon Banania* » et la boîte était illustrée d'un [tirailleur sénégalais](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirailleur_s%C3%A9n%C3%A9galais), bien sûr c'est interdit de nos jours. Voir l'article de Wikipedia sur l'[ami Y'a Bon](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27ami_Y%27a_bon).

Et pour finir rappelons le film de Jean Yann *Moi y'en a vouloir des sous*.